# Overriding flexbox align-items in html dynamic style

Tags: css, flexbox

In the jsfiddle example I have 4 divs side by side, each div having a few elements in column. The first div has a long content, and I need some flexibity when stacking the other columns vertically.

In the CSS, the default is for the column elements to stack at the top, using align-items:

```
div.flex {
    ...
    align-items: flex-start;
}
```

However I need to be able to override it dynamically in inline html style, to be able to stack the other columns either at the top, or stretched or at the bottom:

```
<style type='text/css'>
        #left { 
            align-items: flex-start;
            flex: 1;  
            background-color: beige;
        } 
        #middle { 
            align-items: stretch;
            flex: 1;  
            background-color: lightblue;
        } 
        #right { 
            align-items: flex-end;
            flex: 1;  
            background-color: salmon;
        } 
</style>
```

Although I can modify the vertical stacking in the CSS using align-items, it doesn't work in the inline HTML style when I do it at the ID level. Also flex-end aligns horizontally when its inline and vertically when it's in the CSS. So any help is much appreciated.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nnn32hbt/2/)

Comment: You should use `align-self` when set on the flex item, not `align-items`, which is used on the flex container

Comment: Thanks @Michael_B and @LGSon! align-self fixed the issue. What confused me was that my flex items are flex containers as well.